# How do I mirror an object using the mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can I mirror a cylinder using the **Mirror Modifier** in order to get two cylinders?

I want to edit one of the cylinders and get the same result on the mirrored one.

Answer (score 5):

You have to position your *3D Cursor* away from the cylinder, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and choose the 3rd option- ***Origin to 3D Cursor***. Next add a *Mirror Modifier* and choose the axis. Remember that the mirrored object appears on the same opposite distance from the origin, that's why you have to put your origin away from the Cylinder center, otherwise you will not be able to see any change, as your mirrored object will appear in the same position as your mesh.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Better than changing the objects Origin would be to use an apart from the origin located *Empty* as *Mirror Object* in the Modifier.

1. Add the Cylinder Object (A) that you want to mirror to your Scene.
2. Add an *Empty* *if needed and translate it away from (A)'s origin and rotate it as the following step will use its local transform orientation and it's global position which is shown here:*
   [image: Mirror Object Empty added]
3. Add a *Mirror Modifier* to (A)'s Modifier Stack setting the Empty as the *Mirror Object*.
   [image: Mirrored Cylinder] [image: Mirror Modifier with use of Mirror Object]