# Mirror Modifier creates the other part of model far away from the original

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I'm doing a girl here (the concept is not mine, I'm just training) and when I click on mirror modifier Blender creates the other part of the model far away from the first one, not close like it should

[image]

I have no idea how to change that, does someone know what is the reason it works that way?

Comment: It seems perfectly mirrored to me. The modifier will mirror along the X-axis; you can also describe this as using the YZ-plane as a mirror. Since your background image is already centred around the origin, I don't see the problem.

Comment: I don't even know..it seems that from the side it looks fine but in the middle, it should be together, that's a face in the end, like, for example in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZ2ob8F3sJQ
Mine just doesn't work that way

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right/354 for details about Mirror modifier. It mirrors along origin point by default which in your case is a bit to the left of the object hence there's a gap. In the vid you linked (please use timestamps if sharing) origin point is set to the center line of the cube part so mirrored part is just next to original.

Answer (score 2):

The Mirror modifier works exactly "**as it should**".

Meaning it will mirror the geometry using the object's origin (that orange dot that you see in the girl's forehead) as the axis of symmetry. If your geometry is far away from the origin, the mirrored geometry will be as far away from the origin but on the other side of the axis.

[image]

Read the blender manual page to understand how the tool works:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html?highlight=mirror%20modifier

As an alternative to using the objecct's origin, the mirror modifier can also be used with a control object. As detailed in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49355/1853

Comment: In addition to cegatons always spot on answer you will want to check the box next to clipping in the Mirror Modifier so that when you do bring your mesh to the Origin it doesn't overlap.