# blender's mirror modifier not working how I want it to

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror, error

Hi I am having a problem with blender mirror modifier,because every time I try to mirror my object, it just not directly mirror the object from the middle, I had also got the same problem with the auto mirror add-on, along with some code error. The clipping tool also seems to not be helpful for me either, when I have cut an object in half to be mirrored. I am using v2.81.16, please tell me what is wrong or if there is a simple fix, thanks.
[image: original model][image: When i use mirror modifier]

Comment: The mirror modifier's center is the origin of the object (the origin is an orange dot, find it).  Unless the origin is in what you call the "middle" of your object then it will not work "how you want it"

Comment: [How can I make the mirror modifier work right?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102315/mirror-modifier-creates-the-other-part-of-model-far-away-from-the-original?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was just because the pivot point was not at the middle of my object, because before I had deleted the vertices which did not delete the whole object keeping the pivot point at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You are inside  *Edit mode*. The Blender Mirror modifier takes into account only the changes you make in *Object Mode*.

For changes made in *Edit* mode, you need the mirror option in the *tool* menu (which comes up by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>).

See the following image:

[image]

Comment: Note that the modifier can be enabled to display changes in edit mode as well.

Comment: Ah, it seems you are right, I didn't notice while working I may have used it. Perhaps it didn't work like that in 2.81?

Comment: Anyways @William-Feng should consider downloading 2.83.1 instead, as it is the latest stable release with a lot more bug fixes. It is a LTS release, meaning it will receive bug fixes for long, unlike 2.81

Comment: The ability to preview modifiers in edit mode has been there for a long time.